# Compile xf86-input-libinput and get my version to be used

Tags: software-installation, drivers, compiling, scrolling, wayland

Wayland Libinput has a noticeable 0.5s delay at two-finger scrolling. The setting is in code with the line

```
#define DEFAULT_GESTURE_2FG_SCROLL_TIMEOUT ms2us(500)
```

in the file `evdev-mt-touchpad-gestures.c`. I want to set this delay to another value, but I am not able to make the changes effective.

I've tried recompiling and reinstalling libinput with:

```
./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install
```

or

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

with no result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the new library actually replaces your system's library. On a Debian `amd64` system this would be something like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput.so.10.6.2`; you should copy your new library there:

```
./configure && make && sudo cp -P src/.libs/libinput.so* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

A better approach would be to use modify your distribution's `libinput` package; for example, on Debian:

```
apt-get source libinput
cd libinput-1.1.3
```

Modify `evdev-mt-touchpad-gestures.c` as appropriate, then

```
dch -n "Reduce two-finger scroll timeout."
dch -r ignored
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
sudo dpkg -i ../libinput10*deb
```

(You'd need to have `devscripts` and `dpkg-dev` installed.)

You can do something similar on RPM-based distributions.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I increased the value to 3000ms and scrolling still delay 500ms.

Comment: I take it you've restarted X after installing the modified library?

Comment: Of course. In fact I tried rebooting the PC.

Comment: OK; are you using Weston?